# Pointers and Arrays in C. The Concept Not Quite Clicking.

Tags: c

I am doing practice in C by making a program that checks whether an array of chars is a palindrome or not by using pointers. I am still a little iffy on pointers in general, but I have no clue why this program is not working. It gives the correct output for single letter checks but for more than one character it always returns "is not a palindrome". I am really sorry if this is not a good question, but I would really like to learn what I am doing wrong so that I can grasp the concept of pointers better.

This is the program:

```
int is_palindrome2(const char *phrase, int length)
{
  char i = 0;
  const char *end;

  phrase = &i;
  end = phrase + length - 1;

  while(phrase < end)
  {
    if((*phrase) != (*end))
    {
      return 0;
    }
    phrase++;
    end--;
  }

  return 1;

}
```

And this is what output I get from the command prompt(The first test was by subscription and the second test is this function)

```
Testing #1: a is a palindrome
Testing #2: a is a palindrome

Testing #1: ab is not a palindrome
Testing #2: ab is not a palindrome

Testing #1: aa is a palindrome
Testing #2: aa is not a palindrome

Testing #1: abcdcba is a palindrome
Testing #2: abcdcba is not a palindrome

Testing #1: madamImadam is a palindrome
Testing #2: madamImadam is not a palindrome
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Remove `phrase = &i;`.

Comment: What's that: `phrase = &i;` ?

Comment: `phrase = &i;` what do you think this is doing?

Comment: @Niloct Oh my gosh. I see now. Thank you so much. when I tried to initialize end before I forgot that I had set it to just a char instead of a constant before so the only way it would work is if I set phrase to something. But now since I set it to constant that becomes the source of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: No problem @adsf!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
phrase = &i;
```

You're overwriting the value of `phrase`, which points to your string, with the address of an unrelated local variable.  Then any pointer arithmetic you perform on `phrase` works off of the address of `i`.  This will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if `length` is greater than 1 because the pointer arithmetic will take you past the bounds of `i` (or one address past `i`).

There's no need for that statement.  Get rid of it, and `phrase` starts at the start of the string as it should.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see my mistake now!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more visual explanation of what's happening, for those interested.

```
char array[] = "abba";
is_palindrome2(array,4);
```

`array` is convertible to a pointer that points like this

```
| 'a' | 'b' | 'b' | 'a' | NULL |
   ^
 array
```

So when you call the function, you can imagine the pointer pointing towards

```
| 'a' | 'b' | 'b' | 'a' | NULL |
   ^
 phrase
```

When you do

```
char i = 0;
phrase = &i;
```

You actually reassign the pointer to point towards somewhere else.

```
| 'a' | 'b' | 'b' | 'a' | NULL |       ...       | 0 |
                                                   ^
                                                phrase
```

Comment: That's very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `phrase = &i;`, it overwrites the `phrase` pointer.

Also, keep in mind that when calling your function (as it's currently implemented), length should be **exclusive** of the `null` character.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now!